# HBase zookeeper.znode.parent mismatch error

Tags: tomcat, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I'm deploying a Tomcat webapp that accesses a local HBase table. I'm running Tomcat 7.0.47 and HBase 0.94.6 (from HDP 1.3.2, installed w/ Ambari). When I try to run the webapp, it gives a `zookeeper.znode.parent` mismatch error in catalina.out:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0
13/11/13 12:06:54 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.5-111--1, built on 08/20/2013 01:42 GMT
13/11/13 12:06:54 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:host.name=%MYHOSTNAME%
13/11/13 12:06:54 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.version=1.6.0_31
13/11/13 12:06:54 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
13/11/13 12:06:54 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.home=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre
13/11/13 12:06:54 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.class.path=/usr/lib/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/lib/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
13/11/13 12:06:54 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
13/11/13 12:06:54 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/usr/lib/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/temp
13/11/13 12:06:54 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
13/11/13 12:06:54 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
13/11/13 12:06:54 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=amd64
13/11/13 12:06:54 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=2.6.32-358.6.1.el6.x86_64
13/11/13 12:06:54 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=root
13/11/13 12:06:54 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/root
13/11/13 12:06:54 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/home/%MYUSER%
13/11/13 12:06:54 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
13/11/13 12:06:54 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this process is 2463@%MYHOSTNAME%
13/11/13 12:06:54 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (Unable to locate a login configuration)
13/11/13 12:06:54 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
13/11/13 12:06:54 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x1424e72bdee003b, negotiated timeout = 40000
13/11/13 12:06:54 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
13/11/13 12:06:54 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Closed zookeeper sessionid=0x1424e72bdee003b
13/11/13 12:06:54 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
13/11/13 12:06:54 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x1424e72bdee003b closed
```

I've checked that my hbase-site.xml has the right value for `zookeeper.znode.parent` (/hbase-unsecure) and that the hbase-site.xml file for my webapp matches that. HBase is working fine on it's own, I'm able to create tables and load data into them. So I'm uncertain where the mismatch is occurring. The only other thing I can think of is that the zookeeper.jar was compiled with a different zookeeper.znode.parent location defined.